# ngx-toastr not working in fullscreen mode(requestFullscreen())

Tags: angular, overlay, ngx-toastr

i am using requestFullscreen() [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullscreen) to view my component in full screen.
i have a button in this component which on clicking displays a toast message(using ngx-toastr) everything is working fine in normal mode but in full screen mode this toastr is going behind the container(which is currently displayed as an overlay using requestFullscreen() ).
I tried adding
`provide: OverlayContainer, useClass: FullscreenOverlayContainer`  as a provider in app.module and this is allowing me to show toaster messages from `@angular/material/snack-bar` but there is no change in the toastr messages from `ngx-toast`.

```
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
...
...
```

```
constructor(
private toastService: ToastrService,
private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
){}
...
...
```

inside a button click function

```
this.toastService.warning('Saved changes cannot be edited.');  
      this.snackBar.open('Snack bar opened', 'OK', {
        duration: 5000
      });
```

here the first toastr is not being displayed where as the second one is being displayed

Comment: please provide a stackblitz with the issue replicated for debugging!

Answer (score 0):

we can achieve this by displaying our toastr in a custom component [ngx-toastr read.me](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr/blob/master/README.md#:%7E:text=Put%20toasts%20in%20your%20own%20container&text=Add%20ToastContainerModule%20to%20the%20ngModule,is%20announced%20by%20screen%20readers.&text=Add%20a%20div%20with%20toastContainer%20directive%20on%20it.)

app.module

```
import { ToastContainerDirective, ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
.
.
.
@NgModule({
imports: [
        ToastrModule.forRoot(),
        ToastContainerDirective
    ],
)}
```

in html template add `toastContainer`

```
<div fullscreen>
 <div toastContainer aria-live="polite"></div>
</div>
```

in ts component file

```
constructor(private toastService: ToastrService){}
```

```
@ViewChild(ToastContainerDirective, { static: true })
  toastContainer: ToastContainerDirective;
```

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.toastService.overlayContainer = this.toastContainer
```

this are the changes which allowed me to use ngx-toastr in fullscreen mode.
what I did here is basically displayed the toastr inside a div which is a child of the div with fullscreen functionality